# Nuget package downgrade on .NET 6 Docker build using Central Package Management

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

TL;DR:

> When I build my .NET 6 ASP.NET console app locally, the restore uses the versions of my dependencies that I specify, but when I build within the official .NET 6 docker image, it downgrades the packages to old and incompatible versions suitable for old versions of the .NET Framework.  Please help!

I have a .NET 6 ASP.NET WebAPI app that runs as a self hosted console application in a docker container.  It works as expected when built and run locally, but when I attempt to build it using the official microsoft .NET 6 image, it downgrades several of my packages to an old *incompatible* version.  I'm using Central Package Management.

Here's the dockerfile - pretty vanilla:

```
  #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
  
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
  WORKDIR /app
  EXPOSE 80
  EXPOSE 5000
  
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
  WORKDIR /src
  COPY ["src/simul8.runtime.host/simul8.runtime.host.csproj", "src/simul8.runtime.host/"]
  COPY ["src/simul8.core/simul8.core.csproj", "src/simul8.core/"]
  COPY ["src/simul8.metamodel/simul8.metamodel.csproj", "src/simul8.metamodel/"]
  COPY ["src/simul8.metamodel.metadata/simul8.metamodel.metadata.csproj", "src/simul8.metamodel.metadata/"]
  COPY ["src/simul8.runtime/simul8.runtime.csproj", "src/simul8.runtime/"]
  RUN dotnet restore "src/simul8.runtime.host/simul8.runtime.host.csproj"
  COPY . .
  WORKDIR "/src/src/simul8.runtime.host"
  RUN dotnet build "simul8.runtime.host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
  
  FROM build AS publish
  RUN dotnet publish "simul8.runtime.host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
  
  FROM base AS final
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "simul8.runtime.host.dll"]
```

The `csproj` file for the project `simul8.metamodel`, which is one of the failure points:

```xml
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <RootNamespace>Simul8.Metamodel</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" />
    </ItemGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="AST\ast.nodes.tt" />
    </ItemGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="AST\ast.nodes.tt" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

It's the `Antlr4.Runtime.Standard` package that is being downgraded.  In the central package version file, I ask for `4.10.1`:

```xml
  <Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
      <CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>true</CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageVersion Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.10.1" />
      <PackageVersion Include="AutoFixture">
        <Version>4.17.0</Version>
      </PackageVersion>
      <PackageVersion Include="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" Version="4.17.0" />
      <PackageVersion Include="AutoFixture.NUnit3">
        <Version>4.17.0</Version>
      </PackageVersion>
      <PackageVersion Include="AutоFiхture.NUnit3" Version="4.17.0" />
      . . . snip . . .
    </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

But when I run a `docker buildx bake -f docker-compose.yml` in powershell or WSL - after a full system prune - I get errors like the following:

```
  /src/src/simul8.core/simul8.core.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Antlr4.Runtime.Standard does not contain an inclusive lower bound. 
  Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results. [/src/src/simul8.runtime.host/simul8.runtime.host.csproj]
  /src/src/simul8.core/simul8.core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, 
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, 
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. 
  [/src/src/simul8.runtime.host/simul8.runtime.host.csproj]
```

My understanding from the docs was that setting an explicit version like `4.10.1` is the same as setting a lower bound.  I also tried using `4.10.*` and `[4.10.1, )`, but it made no difference.

Here are the .NET SDKs installed locally on my machine (they are all `net6.0` compatible)

```bash
  $ dotnet --list-sdks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           in pwsh at 11:03:44
  6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.400-preview.22330.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I'm building locally on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0

The version `4.6.0` of the ANTLR4 runtime package is indeed not compatible with my code, and I can't roll back to using it, since there are features in v4.10 that I depend on.

What's happening?

Comment: Does it work when **not** using _Central Package Management_?

Comment: Not sure TBH. I’ve mentioned central package management simply in case it jogged a memory with a reader. I don’t know that it has anything to do with the problem at all.

Comment: I'd suggest giving it a try, just to remove it from the equation

Comment: As I suspected, CPM had nothing to do with the issue in the end.  Answer provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer myself, in case it proves to be useful to others.

The solution for me was to remove the standard Visual Studio generated multi-stage docker file.  As a (presumably) efficiency step, the generated approach was to transfer the project dependencies into the image separately, and then `dotnet restore` the project being built.  For whatever reason, this had the result of confusing restore, and leading to the downgrade.

Here's the simpler dockerfile that worked in the end:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/simul8.buildagent"
RUN dotnet build "simul8.buildagent.csproj" -c Debug  --verbosity=normal --no-incremental --self-contained --use-current-runtime -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "simul8.buildagent.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "simul8.buildagent.exe"]
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue you are, but I'm struggling to understand the change you made. By chance is it possible to show the difference of what predated your changes in this dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, since you've found the workaround. But for those who doesn't want to bloat the build context in the similar situations:

To have the Central Package Management working you need to explicitly copy the Directory.Packages.props file and place it alongside the csproj/sln file you are going to restore.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  In my case I copy across a whole bunch of  subprojects into the build image.  Do, you mean that `Directory.Packages.props` needs to be copied into each of the sub-project's folders?  That seems somewhat... redundant?

Comment: This is redundant, unless you need some specific version that differs from the one set in the main props file. From my experience I can say, it's enough to put the props file in the Docker's WORKDIR for a build container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy "Directory.Packages.props" into the Docker container in order to restore packages properly.

like this:

```
COPY ["/Directory.Packages.props","/"]
```